# How to share realm objects between screens

Tags: swift, realm

I am working on an app written in Swift, which needs e.g. the data of the currently logged-in User on multiple screens and after updating it from an API to save the data.

What is the best practice to get this data? Get the instance on every occurrence from the Database by a selection like this:

```
do {
    let realm = try Realm()
    let result = realm.objects(User).filter("name = \(loggedInPlayerName)")

    if result.count > 0 {
        return result.first
    }
}
```

Or sharing it after getting it once by a (singleton) SessionService or something similar?

Or have the Player Model Object some selection method like User().getLoggedInUser() which has the above written method to select an instance?

Would appreciate some thoughts on how to do that correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct I would do something like that! I assume loggedInPlayName is a unique id, so you could set the property name as a primary key.

Then I would do:

`let user = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(User.self, key: loggedInPlayerName)`